# List key and value of common occurrences in value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```php
$personas = [
'Franz' => [
  'interests' => 'all',
  'gender' => 'maskulin'
],
'Sissi' => [
  'interests' => 'kitesurfing', 'tennis',
  'gender' => 'feminin'
],
'Egon' => [
  'interests' => 'kitesurfing', 'cinema';
  'gender' => 'maskulin'
],
'Maria' => [
  'interests' => 'cinema', 'soccer',
  'gender' => 'feminin'
]
];
```

**List the data of persons who have indicated in interests all or Kitesurfing**

```php
 foreach($personas as $person => $kitesurfing) {
        echo .$person.' is '.$gender.', ';
    }
   echo 'and all '.$personal_number.' '.$kitesurfing.' like!';
```

**expected result**

> **Franz** is maskulin, **Sissi** is feminin, **Egon** is maskulin, and all 3 **kitesurfing** like!

Comment: You also need to have if statements. Simple foreach will just give you all elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$personas = [
    'Franz' => [
        'interests' => ['all'],
        'gender' => 'maskulin'
    ],
    'Sissi' => [
        'interests' => ['kitesurfing', 'tennis'],
        'gender' => 'feminin'
    ],
    'Egon' => [
        'interests' => ['kitesurfing', 'cinema'],
        'gender' => 'maskulin'
    ],
    'Maria' => [
        'interests' => ['cinema', 'soccer'],
        'gender' => 'feminin'
    ]
];
$interests = ['all', 'kitesurfing'];
$filtered = array_filter($personas, function($v) use ($interests) {
    return array_intersect($interests, $v['interests']);
});
var_export($filtered);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'Franz' => 
    array (
    'interests' => 
    array (
        0 => 'all',
    ),
    'gender' => 'maskulin',
    ),
    'Sissi' => 
    array (
    'interests' => 
    array (
        0 => 'kitesurfing',
        1 => 'tennis',
    ),
    'gender' => 'feminin',
    ),
    'Egon' => 
    array (
    'interests' => 
    array (
        0 => 'kitesurfing',
        1 => 'cinema',
    ),
    'gender' => 'maskulin',
    ),
)
```